# populate column using loop based on value in row index 0

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a `DataFrame` where I want to populate a column which currently has a date only in the first row, all other rows in the column are blank (`None`).

Using the value in index row `0` of `df['date']` column, I have  written a loop that gives me a date in each subsequent row which is 7 days previous of the date in the previous row.

```
import numpy as pd

first_date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].loc[0])


date_list = [first_date]
count = 0
while count < (len(df) -1):
    count +=1
    print(count)
    subtract_days = count * 7
    latest_date = first_date  - timedelta(days=subtract_days)
    print(latest_date)
    date_list.append(latest_date)

print(date_list)

df['date_1'] = date_list
```

However, this requires creating a new column df['date_1'], deleting the existing df['date'] and renaming the new.

What would be a more efficient way of doing the same?

Comment: check [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
# set your date column as index
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# generate dates for 7 days descending for periods equal to length of the dataframe
df.index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], freq='-7d', periods=df.shape[0])
```

This can be done without setting as an index as well.

```
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start=df.iloc[0]['date'], freq='-7d', periods=df.shape[0])
```